# can i use multiprocessing with several different method at the sametime in python2/3

Tags: python, subprocess

well,i want to make my two different methods proceeding at the sametime.
i wish to accomplish by multiprocessing,but i found all of examples are proceeding the same methods with multiprocessors,not the different method with the multiprocessors.
my code is as follows,it proceeds in sequence,not out of sequence

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import multiprocessing
import time
#def thread_test(num1,num2):
#x=5
def haha(num1):
    for i in range(num1):
       time.sleep(1)
       print('a')
def hehe(num2):
    for i in range(num2):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('b')
if __name__=='__main__':

        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
        pool.apply_async(haha(5))
        pool.apply_async(hehe(5))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print("done")
```

the print is as follows

```
a
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
b
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has been answered before but I cannot find where to duplicate this and I need a bit more than a comment to describe what is happening, so here it goes:

The problem with your code is that you are in fact not executing your functions in different processes. Instead you are trying to execute the return value of your functions `haha` and `hehe` in new processes. And since you have not defined any `return` value, they return `None`.

`.apply_async` (and similar functions) need to be called with the bare function name as first parameter and then the arguments as a second parameter (wraped as a `tuple`). This is needed due to the execution order defined by Python (and virtually all other programming languages) where the function argumnets are evaluated before the function itself. Thus, when you call a function with an argument being another function *call* then the inner function call is evaluated first.

The solution to this, is therefore to call the outer function, not with an inner function call, but with the bare function name (which then works as a reference to the inner function) and then the arguments to the inner function as a separate argument to the outer function. This way there is nothint to evaluate before the outer function starts to execute. For the situation at hand, the solution is thus simple. Just change your code as:

```
#-*-coding:utf-8-*-
import multiprocessing
import time

def haha(num1):
    for i in range(num1):
       time.sleep(1)
       print('a')

def hehe(num2):
    for i in range(num2):
        time.sleep(1)
        print('b')

if __name__=='__main__':
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
        pool.apply_async(haha, (5,)) # instead of pool.apply_async(haha(5))
        pool.apply_async(hehe, (5,)) # instead of pool.apply_async(hehe(5))
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print("done")
```

I hope this explanation makes sense to you, and helps you to watch out for these situations in the future.

Comment: i see.  in my opinion，my func has finished before being put into pool.  thanks a lot，what you said teaches me much.